# Что означают в Си эти записи? 1) "[%m[^]]" 2) "%m[^=]=%ms"

Tags: c

Что означают данные форматы, как они работают?

1. `"[%m[^]]"` при вызове:

   ```
   sscanf(line, "[%m[^]]", &subs);
   ```
2. `"%m[^=]=%ms"` при вызове:

   ```
   sscanf(line, "%m[^=]=%ms", &variable, &value);
   ```

Comment: См. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf, таблицу форматов, раздел `[set]`.